# zypper: command not found in SUSE linux

Tags: linux, suse, zypper

I was not aware that zypper is like yum for SUSE. I deleted that file from bin, now I am not able to install any application through it. I throws an error that

> sudo: zypper: command not found

How do I install zypper back and make it work like as normal?

Comment: You shoud better ask on http://serverfault.com/ .

Comment: Don't use the words "asap" or "please"

Comment: Which version of Suse and architecture are you using ?

Comment: @STBLand: I think "please" is OK, except where the resulting phrase sounds like begging (we get a lot of "please help me", and I would doubt it encourages people to reply faster). You're certainly right about ASAP though.

Comment: SUSE Version is 12 and architecture is x86_64

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your system and architecture, find Zypper package file (RPM) in online repository (i.e. http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/13.2/repo/oss/suse/i586/ ), download it (wget) and install it (rpm -i) :

```
wget http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/13.2/repo/oss/suse/i586/zypper-1.11.14-2.1.i586.rpm

sudo rpm -ivh zypper-1.11.14-2.1.i586.rpm
```

Comment: It failed due to two dependencies:
1>  libzypp.so.1429()(64bit) is needed by zypper-1.11.14-2.1.x86_64 

2>  libzypp.so.1429(ZYPP_plain)(64bit) is needed by zypper-1.11.14-2.1.x86_64

but i already have the newer version of those (package libsolv-tools-0.6.14-2.13.1.x86_64 [which is newer than libsolv-tools-0.6.6-1.1.x86_64) is already installed
] and hence I was not able to install the exact version of the dependency the zypper is ask for. How do i proceed, should I get the updated version of zypper?

Comment: zypper-1.12.23-1.3.x86_64 this was my zypper earlier

Comment: @Niteshkumar this answer is example how to deal with that situation , not step by step guide.

Comment: @Niteshkumar, I am facing the same issue... Nitesh have you found the solution for the above issue?

Comment: @NeerajKumarYadav I had the ISO image of the SUSE I was working with. I extracted ISO and got the "zypper" file from there and pasted it back to the bin where I deleted it from. Try the same If you have the iso of the same SUSE verison.